# Multiple local file upload React + Node JS not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, file-upload

I am trying to upload multiple image files for my project.

Single file upload worked as expected but multiple file upload fails. The response from the server though is a 200 ...

// Server

```
export const uploadFiles = async (req, res) => {

  let storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function (req, file, cb) {
      cb(null, "public");
    },
    filename: function (req, file, cb) {
      console.log(file) // this log returned the image when it was a single file, and returns empty on image array
      cb(null, Date.now() + "-" + file.originalname);
    },
  });

  let upload = multer({ storage: storage }).array("file");

  upload(req, res, function (err) {
    if (err instanceof multer.MulterError) {
      return res.status(500).json(err);
    } else if (err) {
      return res.status(500).json(err);
    }
    return res.status(200).send(req.file);
  });
};
```

// Client

```
 const [files, setFiles] = useState([]);

 const onChangeHandler = (event) => {
    let newArray = [...files];
    newArray.push(event.target.files);
    setFiles(newArray);
  };

 const onClickHandler = () => {
    const data = new FormData();
    files.forEach((element) => {
      data.append("file", element);
    });

    axios
      .post("http://localhost:5000/upload", data)
      .then((res) => console.log(res.statusText))
      .catch((err) => console.log(err));
  };


  return (
      <div>
        <input
          type="file"
          multiple
          onChange={onChangeHandler}
        />
        <button onClick={onClickHandler}>Upload images</button>
    </div>
  );
};
```

When i `console.log(files)`, the response in console is the following

```
[FileList, FileList, FileList]
```

Does somebody know an approach that could work?

Thanks in advance!